# How to sort a string into a map and print the results

Tags: java, string, split, hashmap

I have a string in the format `nm=Alan&hei=72&hair=brown`

I would like to split this information up, add a conversion to the first value and print the results in the format

```
nm Name Alan
hei Height 72
hair Hair Color brown
```

I've looked at various methods using the split function and hashmaps but have had no luck piecing it all together.

Any advice would be very useful to me.

Comment: Could you jot down what you've tried?

Comment: Is this homework ? Can you explain to us what you tried so far ? You're on the right track with split and hashmaps, though. Think about spliting twice ...

Comment: Is that a part of URL or just a string with similiar formatting?

Comment: `nm Name Alan`, where does `Name` come from? Quite frankly, I don't understand how your results gets generated. Also, with `hair Hair Color brown`, *Hair Color`???

Comment: Hi - this isn't homework, I am working on a little script to translate FIX protocol messages into a readable format. Only I don't know my arse from my elbow in Java.

Comment: Thanks all for the quick and informative responses!

Answer (score 3):

```
Map<String, String> aliases = new HashMap<String, String>();
aliases.put("nm", "Name");
aliases.put("hei", "Height");
aliases.put("hair", "Hair Color");

String[] params = str.split("&"); // gives you string array: nm=Alan, hei=72, hair=brown

for (String p : params) {
    String[] nv = p.split("=");
    String name = nv[0];
    String value = nv[1];
    System.out.println(nv[0] + " " + aliases.get(nv[0]) + " " + nv[1]);
}
```

I really do not understand what you problem was...

Comment: Just a beginner, that's all. Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

A HashMap consists of many key, value pairs. So when you use [split](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), devise an appropriate regex (&). Once you have your string array, you can use one of the elements as the key (think about which element will make the best key). However, you may now be wondering- "how do I place the rest of elements as the values?". Perhaps you can create a new class which stores the rest of the elements and use objects of this class as values for the hashmap.

Then printing becomes easy- merely search for the value of the corresponding key. This value will be an object; use the appropriate method on this object to retrieve the elements and you should be able to print everything.

Also, remember to handle exceptions in your code. e.g. check for nulls, etc.

Another thing: your qn mentions the word "sort". I don't fully get what that means in this context...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
static final String DELIMETER = "&"
Map<String,String> map = ...
map.put("nm","Name");
map.put("hei","Height");
map.put("hair","Hair color");

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String input = "nm=Alan&hei=72&hair=brown"
String[] splitted = input.split(DELIMETER);
for(Stirng str : splitted){
     int index = str.indexOf("=");     
     String key = str.substring(0,index);
     builder.append(key);
     builder.append(map.get(key));
     builder.append(str.substring(index));
     builder.append("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, String> propsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> propAlias = new HashMap<String, String>();

propAlias.put("nm", "Name");
propAlias.put("hei", "Height");
propAlias.put("hair", "Hair Color");

String[] props = input.split("&");

if (props != null && props.length > 0) {
    for (String prop : props) {
        String[] propVal = prop.split("=");

        if (propVal != null && propVal.length == 2) {
            propsMap.put(propVal[0], propVal[1]);
        }
    }
}

for (Map.Entry tuple : propsMap.getEntrySet()) {
    if (propAlias.containsKey(tuple.getKey())) {
        System.out.println(tuple.getKey() + " " + propAlias.get(tuple.getKey()) + " " + tuple.getValue());
    }
}
```